# How to get variables and it's values from a variable?

Tags: php

I want to know how to get variables and it's values from a variable?

Here is the sample code;

```
$x = 10;
$y = 20;
$z = 30;

$sum = $x * 5; // It has only one variable
echo $sum; // Page # 1

$sum = ($x * 5) + ($y * 5); // It has two variables
echo $sum; // Page # 2

$sum = ($x * 5) + ($y * 5) + ($z * 5); // It has three variables
echo $sum; // Page # 3
```

Now I want to get the variables inside of the variable **$sum** and their values to output a breakup of the calculation.

Something like this;

**----- Page # 1 -----**

**X:** 10 * 5 = 50

**----- Page # 2 -----**

**X:** 10 * 5 = 50

**Y:** 20 * 5 = 100

**Sum:** X + Y = 150

**----- Page # 3 -----**

**X:** 10 * 5 = 50

**Y:** 20 * 5 = 100

**Z:** 30 * 5 = 150

**Sum:** X + Y + Z = 300

Is there any PHP function or any other solution to achieve this without making any changes to the variable **$sum**?

I know I can do it in other ways, but the problem is; I can't change the code **$sum** as it's required to change it on thousands of pages. It would be highly appreciated if anyone could help me with this.

**Thanks in advance :-)**

Comment: `$sum` only contains the result of the calculation, not the way that result was achieved. As far as I'm aware, there is no way to look at `$sum` and work it backwards to discover that it was made up from adding `$x`, `$y` and `$z`.

Comment: Thats not how variables work. They store the VALUE of the calculation not the calculation itself

Comment: If I gave you an example result of `90`, could _you_ tell me which _exact_ combination of x, y and z I used to get it? What, you can't, because there's multiple different ways, to get that result ...? Well then how should any algorithm do it? It could at most determine _all_ possible combinations that lead to that result, but that probably won't be particularly helpful here. (Although it isn't really clear so far, which _actual_ problem you are even trying to solve here.)

Comment: `All I need to know is what variables are inside of the $sum variable`...but there are no variables "inside" the `$sum` variable. You seem to have misunderstood how computer programs work. All `$sum` contains is its current value at that moment. For example, when you execute `$sum = ($x * 5) + ($y * 5);`, `$sum` does not afterwards contain `"($x * 5) + ($y * 5)"`, it contains the **result of** `($x * 5) + ($y * 5)` (which in this case is `150`). And as CBroe explained, knowing only the result does not tell you how the result was calculated.

Comment: A variable in any language is in fact an address of a piece on memory in which the value is held. That address points to the 32 or 64 bits that are required to hold that value, **and nothing else**. Only a value, and nothing at all about how that value was created

Comment: There is no other solution. Asking repeatedly doesn't change the facts. If there was something else to do, we would have told you by now. Why do you need to do this anyway? If someone asked you to do it, maybe you should go back to them and explain the time / cost involved, and then see how much they _really_ need it, before you start working on it. Any work is always a tradeoff between the cost and the benefit, so if you explain the effort involved then you give them the choice to decide if it's worth it or not.

Comment: No, it's a reasonable question, and you got an answer. Like I said though, go back and ask if you really "have" to do the work, based on the likely effort involved. Give the people requesting the full information to make a decision

Comment: I rolled back [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69402340/revisions)...please don't completely destroy the question, because it makes the existing answers and comments nonsensical for future readers. Tweaks are fine, that's what editing is for...completely removing the original content is not. If you have a new question, start a new post about it (however I would suggest putting a lot more detail into it then you did, it was very vague and would likely just be closed - see [ask] for guidance). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to use `$sum` to retrieve the calculations or input values which were used to give it its current value. PHP does not work like that. As far as I am aware, no programming language currently provides that.

A variable simply contains its current value...it does not contain any other variables or calculations, or keep a history of how it got like that.

The only way to get the output you've specified is to directly echo the data explicitly from the original data, for example:

```
$x = 10;
$y = 20;
$z = 30;

// Page # 1
$sum = $x * 5;
echo "X: ".$x."* 5 = ".$sum;

// Page # 2
$sum = ($x * 5) + ($y * 5);
echo "X: ".$x."* 5 = ".($x * 5);
echo "Y: ".$y."* 5 = ".($y * 5);
echo "Sum: X + Y = ".$sum;

// Page # 3
$sum = ($x * 5) + ($y * 5) + ($z * 5);
echo "X: ".$x."* 5 = ".($x * 5);
echo "Y: ".$y."* 5 = ".($y * 5);
echo "Z: ".$z."* 5 = ".($z * 5);
echo "Sum: X + Y + Z = ".$sum;
```

Comment: Hey Dyson, Thanks for taking your time to post this answer rather than just commenting. I really appreciate that. But the problem is, the breakup coding goes on an included page while sums are on different pages with different variables. The breakup output should change dynamically based on the variables inside of the $sum variable. Is there any other way?

Comment: No, it's not possible. That was the point of my answer :-). You a) can't change something dynamically based on something which hasn't happened yet (I assume the include happens _before_ the sum is calculated?), and b) can't use a variable to detect what calculations were used to bring it to its current value. What is the purpose of wanting to do this? Has someone given you an unachievable requirement, or is it just for your own troubleshooting purposes?

Comment: a) No, after the sum.

Comment: Well ok, but b) still applies anyway so it's irrelevant really.